# как закрыть функцию def func в python

Tags: python

как закрыть функцию def
я пишу всё правильно но при запуске не выводит

код такой:

```
def corrector(string, width, symbol, ):
    
    string = (input(" "))
    symbol = (input(" "))
    width = string + symbol
    print(width)
```

Comment: А вы ее вызываете?

Comment: И зачем задавать входные аргументы функции, если вы их сразу же уничтожаете, заменяя на инпуты и вычисления? Есть подозрение, что вы не понимаете, что такое функция

Answer (score 0):

Очень непонятный вопрос. Но функцию можно использовать примерно вот так:

```
def corrector(string, symbol):
    width = string + symbol
    return width

string = input(" ")
symbol = input(" ")

result = corrector(string, symbol)
print(result)
```

Сперва получаем значение из инпутов, затем передаем их в функцию и что-то там с ними делаем. Через ретурн возвращаем результат и выводим на экран.